# Maximum Vpp that doesn't change the output offset

Tags: amplifier

I have a homework problem:

> We have a non-inverting amplifier, \$G=+20V/V\$, which amplifies a perfect square wave, \$\overline{V_{IN}}=0.5V, \ V_{PP}=0.05V, \ f=50kHz\$. The output signal has offset equal to \$\overline{V_{OUT}}=10V\$. We also know that the smallest resistance value in this circuit is \$2k\Omega\$. What is the maximum \$V_{PP}\$ (peak peak input value) for this circuit, that will not change \$\overline{V_{OUT}}\$?
>
> \$f_c=2MHz, \ f_{DP}=10HZ, \ SR=1V/\mu s, \ |V_{OUT(max)}|=13.5V\$

And, to be quite honest, I do not know what should I check and what will cause the change

EDIT:

The schematics:

[image]

And the smallest resistance will be \$R_r\$, i.e. the compensating resistor.

\$R_r=R_1 || R_2=2k\Omega \wedge R_2=19R_1\rightarrow R_1=2.11k\Omega, \ R_2=40k\Omega\$

Comment: If Vin = 0.5 volts then how can Vp-p = 0.05 volts? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @Andyaka It is clear, if you know what does a line over a variable stand for. And it stands for "the average value" aka offset.

Comment: OK, I was having a senior moment LOL. On a serious note, I think you need to specify the supply rails and clear up what you mean by "We also know that the smallest resistance value in this circuit is 2kΩ".

Comment: @Andyaka My professor told us that at this course \$|V_{supply}|=15V\$, and op-amp is in dual-supply mode, hence \$|V_{OUT(max)}=13.5V\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the average input voltage does not change, an ideal amplifier will produce the same average output voltage. The average output voltage thus changes if the non-ideal nature of the actual amplifier kicks in, and does so in a way that affects the negative and the positive part of the square wave differently.

In your exercise, exceeding the slew rate or the gain-bandwidth product will deform the upper and the lower part of the square wave the same way and not affect the average. But if the amplifier *clips* the positive side of the wave at +13.5V, it still has enough headroom on the negative side, due to the large offset voltage.

I hope this answer is able to give you an idea where to start with the task.